# Calender, 7 days one week, viewpager

Tags: java, android, calendar, android-viewpager

I want to make a calendar that shows only 7 days from monday to sunday. At the same time I also want to use viewpager to swipe left and right, each swipe will plus or subtract 1 week. Is there any way to do this? Thank you.

Here is the example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dx4iO.png

Comment: Check this https://github.com/Mulham-Raee/Horizontal-Calendar

Comment: Actually, I need to do it myself, not using the library. Anyway, thank you

Comment: You can use viewpager2 with recycler adapter and try to create items for 7 days for particular years.

Comment: i made it show for 7 days. But now I need it to swipe right and left to go back to the previous week and to the new week. Is there any way. Thanks!

Here is my code: https://github.com/nhat-beo/Calender